# Javascript Validation using ribbon customisation

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Looking for a javascript code which can be written inside a 'CLOSE' ribbon button in CRM which can forcibly close my form on clicking that button. The CLOSE button should work when a field named 'Status reason' has the following custom values: Approved or Not approvedI i.e the validation has to be done on the basis of these values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Xrm.Page.ui.close() is what you need. You can find more info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_close

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the standard "Status Reason" field (`statuscode`):

```
function closeButton() {

    // Replace the numbers with the actual OptionSetValues for your statuscode
    var relevantStatusCodeValues = {
        Approved: 1,
        NotApproved: 2
    };

    var currentStatusCode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("statuscode").getValue();

    switch(currentStatusCode) {
        case relevantStatusCodeValues.Approved:
        case relevantStatusCodeValues.Approved:

            // Ensure nothing gets in the way of closing the record
            Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get().forEach(function(attr) {
                attr.setSubmitMode("never");
            });

            // Close the form
            Xrm.Page.ui.close();

        default:
            // Nothing to do
            break;
    }
}
```

You also probably want to employ a `<ValueRule>` to hide the button when the statuscode isn't one you explicitly support.

Comment: hi Alex your code was really helpful!I would be really grateful if you help me sort this out!Basically i want to write a JS inside the ribbon button which would act like the deactivate button  i.e set the status of the form to inactive when the status reason of the form is either 'approved' or 'not approved'.

Comment: ill use the switch logic just that instead of closing the form the record status should change to inactive ..i.e it should get deactivated. Just the way in crm when we click on deactivate button the status changes to inactive in the same way my ribbon button JS  shud work.

Comment: Xrm.Page.ui.close() ..instead of this can we use some other logic to change the status of the record to inactive.